# In Window Batch - how do I parse CSV file where fields include Comma and double quote

Tags: csv, batch-file

I have an input CSV file, ttt.csv, which is comma delimited, each field may include double quote and comma:

Here is the contents of ttt.csv:

```
"CN=Bar\\,Alex,OU=Users,OU=Headquarters,DC=CORP",Bar,Alex,"Barziza,Alex",BARAAA,aaa@email.com

"CN=Boo\\,Ryan,OU=Users,OU=Headquarters,DC=CORP",Boo,Ryan,"Boo,Ryan",BABBBB,bbb@email.com
```

I would need to loop this file, for each line, I would need to get each of the 6 values and create my SQL insert statement to database.

In my case for Line 2 I would need to get:

```
Value1=       CN=Bar\\,Alex,OU=Users,OU=Headquarters,DC=CORP
Value2=       Boo
Value3=       Ryan
Value4=       Boo,Ryan
Value5=       BABBBB
Value6=       bbb@email.com
```

I used delimiter which includes double quotes and it does not seems working:

```
set str2="CN=Bar\\,Alex,OU=Users,OU=Headquarters,DC=CORP",Bar,Alex,"Barziza,Alex",BAR‌​AAA,aaa@email.com
echo %str2%
for /f "tokens=1 delims=(,")" %%a in ("!str2!") do ( set newstr2=%%a )
echo !newstr2!
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far and describe precisely where you are stuck; remember that SO is not a free code writing service...

Comment: I used delimiter which includes double quotes and it does not seems working:


set str2="CN=Bar\\,Alex,OU=Users,OU=Headquarters,DC=CORP",Bar,Alex,"Barziza,Alex",BARAAA,aaa@email.com
echo %str2%

for /f "tokens=1 delims=(,")" %%a in ("!str2!") do (
set newstr2=%%a
)
echo !newstr2!

Comment: set str2="CN=Bar\\,Alex,OU=Users,OU=Headquarters,DC=CORP",Bar,Alex,"Barziza,Alex",BARAAA,aaa@email.com
    echo %str2%

    for /f "tokens=1 delims=(,")" %%a in ("!str2!") do (
    set newstr2=%%a
    )
    echo !newstr2!

Comment: @PaulZ You're on the right track, but you're making it more difficult than it needs to be.  Try using a plain `for` loop with*out* the `/f` switch and delims.

Comment: I tried to use get double quote delimiter to get the first substring, and later strip first strip & use comma to delimit the remaining but still does not work:

Comment: set str2="CN=Bar\\,Alex,OU=Users,OU=Headquarters,DC=CORP",Bar,Alex,"Barziza,Alex",BARAAA,aaa@email.com
echo %str2%



FOR /F delims^=^"^ tokens^=1 %%G IN ("!str2!") DO set substring=%%G
echo !substring!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I commented above, just use a plain `for` loop -- no `/f`, no `/r`, no `/d`, no `/l`, just a plain, simple `for` loop.  It'll handle CSV delimiters while treating quoted stuff as a single token.

```js
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set str2="CN=Bar\\,Alex,OU=Users,OU=Headquarters,DC=CORP",Bar,Alex,"Barziza,Alex",BARAAA,aaa@email.com
echo %str2%

set idx=0

for %%a in (%str2%) do (
    set "newstr[!idx!]=%%~a"
    set /a idx += 1
)

set newstr
```

Output:

> C:\Users\me\Desktop>test.bat
>   "CN=Bar\\,Alex,OU=Users,OU=Headquarters,DC=CORP",Bar,Alex,"Barziza,Alex",BARAAA,
>   aaa@email.com
>   newstr[0]=CN=Bar\\,Alex,OU=Users,OU=Headquarters,DC=CORP
>   newstr[1]=Bar
>   newstr[2]=Alex
>   newstr[3]=Barziza,Alex
>   newstr[4]=BARAAA
>   newstr[5]=aaa@email.com

---

If your csv data contains unquoted spaces that should not be treated as token delimiters, you can temporarily convert spaces to underscores before splitting, then convert back like this:

```js
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set str2="CN=Ryan\\,David Paul,OU=Users,OU=Singapore,DC=GLOBAL,DC=CORP",Ryan,David Paul,"Ryan, David Paul",RPAUL123,David@aaad.com
echo %str2%

set idx=0

for %%a in (%str2: =_%) do (
    set "str=%%~a"
    set "newstr[!idx!]=!str:_= !"
    set /a idx += 1
)

set newstr
```

You can [read more on substring substitution](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php#Snippets.Replace) if you wish.  Output:

> C:\Users\me\Desktop>test.bat
>   "CN=Ryan\\,David Paul,OU=Users,OU=Singapore,DC=GLOBAL,DC=CORP",Ryan,David Paul,"Ryan, David Paul",RPAUL123,David@aaad.com
>   newstr[0]=CN=Ryan\\,David Paul,OU=Users,OU=Singapore,DC=GLOBAL,DC=CORP
>   newstr[1]=Ryan
>   newstr[2]=David Paul
>   newstr[3]=Ryan, David Paul
>   newstr[4]=RPAUL123
>   newstr[5]=David@aaad.com

Of course, if your data already contains underscores, then use a character it doesn't contain -- a backtick, a tilde, a dollar sign, or something else.

Comment: When I added this block into my codes to read file, I got error:

    FOR /F "eol=; tokens=* delims=" %%i in (FinalUserList.csv) do ( 
            setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
     set str=%%i
 set idx=0

 for %%a in (%str%) do (
      set "newstr[!idx!]=%%~a"
      set /a idx += 1
 )
        echo %newstr[0]%
        echo %newstr[1]%

)

Error message says: Maximum setlocal recursion level reached.

Comment: @PaulZ how about a) placing `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` (only)  before any loops) b) using `endlocal` if you wish / have to use setlocal within the loop?

Comment: I'm afraid this will fail as soon as `str2` contains wildcards like `*` or `?`; furthermore, whitespaces and `;` and `=` are also problematic (unless within `""`)...

Comment: I looked the data file, the issue actually comes from the data. There is one guy that his first name is 2 names with a space:
"CN=Ryan\\, David Paul,OU=Users,OU=Singapore,DC=GLOBAL,DC=CORP",Ryan,David Paul,"Ryan, David Paul",RPAUL123,David@aaad.com

The codes interpret the string as:
newstr[0]=CN=Ryan\\, David Paul,OU=Users,OU=Singapore,DC=GLOBAL,DC=CORP
newstr[1]=Ryan
newstr[2]=David
newstr[3]=Paul
newstr[4]=Ryan, David Paul
newstr[5]=RPAUL123
newstr[6]=David@aaad.com

What really the case should be:
newstr[2]=David Paul
newstr[3]=Ryan, David Paul
newstr[4]=RPAUL123
newstr[5]=David@aaad.com

Comment: How do i modify set "newstr[!idx!]=%%~a" - it seems the space between the first name 'David Paul' has caused the problem.

Comment: Still the problem has not been solved: I got one person in source file, his first name is: "David Anthony". I expect the newstr[2]=David Anthony, but it still gives me "David" only, and caused my string parse one column off. See the result:

newstr[0]=CN=Fernandez\\, David Anthony,OU=Users,DC=GLOBAL,DC=CORP
newstr[1]=Fernandez
newstr[2]=David
newstr[3]=Anthony
newstr[4]=Fernandez, David Anthony
newstr[5]=FERNAD123
newstr[6]=DavidAnthony.Fernand@aaaaccc.com

Comment: @PaulZ And you got this result when running the second script?  Or the first?  If second, what is the value of `%str2%`?

Comment: This does not support external text files, which is often a requirement for batch processing.

Answer (score -1):

```
@echo off
(
echo "CN=Bar\\,Alex,OU=Users,OU=Headquarters,DC=CORP",Bar,Alex,"Barziza,Alex",BARAAA,aaa@email.com
echo "CN=Boo\,Ryan,OU=Users,OU=Headquarters,DC=CORP",Boo,Ryan,"Boo,Ryan",BABBBB,bbb@em
)>%tmp%\tmp.csv

for /f tokens^=^1*^ delims^=^" %%i in (%tmp%\tmp.csv) do (
  echo value0=       "%%i"
  for /f tokens^=^1-6^ delims^=^=^,^" %%a in ("%%j") do (
    echo value1=       %%a&echo value2=       %%b&echo value3=       %%c,%%d
    echo value4=       %%e&echo value5=       %%f&echo:
  )
)
```

output:

```
value0=       "CN=Bar\\,Alex,OU=Users,OU=Headquarters,DC=CORP"
value1=       Bar
value2=       Alex
value3=       Barziza,Alex
value4=       BARAAA
value5=       aaa@email.com

value0=       "CN=Boo\,Ryan,OU=Users,OU=Headquarters,DC=CORP"
value1=       Boo
value2=       Ryan
value3=       Boo,Ryan
value4=       BABBBB
value5=       bbb@em
```

Comment: This does not work. I gave it: `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,"abc (efg, xyz)"`, and it gave me this:  `0= 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,`  and `1= abc (efg` and `2=  xyz`. All it's doing is splitting between a quote it found, and that is wrong. It fails to ignore the comma within the string, which is the point of this question.