# Unable to parse csv with delimiter because of extra comma

Tags: csv, parsing, batch-file

I'm currently trying to parse a csv file in batch but am unable to because of extra commas within "------,----" at the beginning. Also some cvs files don't contain this field so I'm unable to just move my tokens. Here is an example of the csv file:

```
Datasheets,Image,Digi-Key Part Number,Manufacturer Part Number,Manufacturer,Description,Quantity Available,Factory Stock,Unit Price (USD),@ qty,Minimum Quantity,"Packaging","Series","Part Status","Capacitance","Tolerance","Voltage - Rated","Dielectric Material","Number of Capacitors","Circuit Type","Temperature Coefficient","Ratings","Mounting Type","Package / Case","Size / Dimension","Height - Seated (Max)"
"//media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Panasonic%20Capacitors%20PDFs/ECJ-R,ECJ-T_4-Array.pdf",//media.digikey.com/photos/Panasonic%20Photos/ECJ-R%201206%20SERIES.jpg,P10582TR-ND,ECJ-RVC1H150K,Panasonic Electronic Components,CAP ARRAY 15PF 50V NP0 1206,0,0,"Obsolete","0","4000","Tape & Reel (TR)","ECJ-R","Obsolete","15pF","±10%","50V","Ceramic","4","Isolated","C0G, NP0","-","Surface Mount","1206 (3216 Metric)","0.126"" L x 0.063"" W (3.20mm x 1.60mm)","0.037"" (0.95mm)"
"//media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Panasonic%20Capacitors%20PDFs/ECJ-R,ECJ-T_4-Array.pdf",//media.digikey.com/photos/Panasonic%20Photos/ECJ-R%201206%20SERIES.jpg,P10582CT-ND,ECJ-RVC1H150K,Panasonic Electronic Components,CAP ARRAY 15PF 50V NP0 1206,1801,0,"0.45000","0","1","Cut Tape (CT)","ECJ-R","Obsolete","15pF","±10%","50V","Ceramic","4","Isolated","C0G, NP0","-","Surface Mount","1206 (3216 Metric)","0.126"" L x 0.063"" W (3.20mm x 1.60mm)","0.037"" (0.95mm)"
"//media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Panasonic%20Capacitors%20PDFs/ECJ-R,ECJ-T_4-Array.pdf",//media.digikey.com/photos/Panasonic%20Photos/ECJ-R%201206%20SERIES.jpg,P10582DKR-ND,ECJ-RVC1H150K,Panasonic Electronic Components,CAP ARRAY 15PF 50V NP0 1206,1801,0,"Digi-Reel","0","1","Digi-Reel®","ECJ-R","Obsolete","15pF","±10%","50V","Ceramic","4","Isolated","C0G, NP0","-","Surface Mount","1206 (3216 Metric)","0.126"" L x 0.063"" W (3.20mm x 1.60mm)","0.037"" (0.95mm)"
"//media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Panasonic%20Capacitors%20PDFs/ECJ-R,ECJ-T_4-Array.pdf",//media.digikey.com/photos/Panasonic%20Photos/ECJ-R%201206%20SERIES.jpg,P10580TR-ND,ECJ-RVC1H100F,Panasonic Electronic Components,CAP ARRAY 10PF 50V NP0 1206,0,0,"Obsolete","0","4000","Tape & Reel (TR)","ECJ-R","Obsolete","10pF","±1pF","50V","Ceramic","4","Isolated","C0G, NP0","-","Surface Mount","1206 (3216 Metric)","0.126"" L x 0.063"" W (3.20mm x 1.60mm)","0.037"" (0.95mm)"
"//media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Panasonic%20Capacitors%20PDFs/ECJ-R,ECJ-T_4-Array.pdf",//media.digikey.com/photos/Panasonic%20Photos/ECJ-R%201206%20SERIES.jpg,P10580CT-ND,ECJ-RVC1H100F,Panasonic Electronic Components,CAP ARRAY 10PF 50V NP0 1206,0,0,"Obsolete","0","1","Cut Tape (CT)","ECJ-R","Obsolete","10pF","±1pF","50V","Ceramic","4","Isolated","C0G, NP0","-","Surface Mount","1206 (3216 Metric)","0.126"" L x 0.063"" W (3.20mm x 1.60mm)","0.037"" (0.95mm)"
```

Here is an example of my code:

```
FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=3-6 delims=, " %%A IN (File.csv) DO (

ECHO %%A,%%B,%%D,%%C
)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32969382/1243048

Comment: Well, the CSV data are 100% correct according to [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc4180), very good explained in Wikipedia article about [comma-separated values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values). The mistake made here was the decision to parse the CSV file with a batch file processed by Windows __command__ processor `cmd.exe` designed for executing commands and applications and not really for anything else. It would be much better to use VBScript or PowerShell for this task which have both built-in support for parsing CSV files.

Comment: Can confirm, the CSV file is correct. For example, in Python, parsing it takes no more effort than `reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)`.

Comment: So in essence you want to get four columns 3-6 and reverse 5th and 6th on output to get `"Digi-Key Part Number","Manufacturer Part Number","Description","Manufacturer"`. As suggested using a script language which ***understands*** csv is much more appropriate, here powershell: `import-csv .\File.csv -Header (1..6|%{"H$_"})|Select H3,H4,H6,H5|ConvertTo-Csv -Not|select-object -skip 1|set-content newfile.csv` If you really want to drop the header, increase `-skip 2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Funny that this question came up. A couple weeks ago I solved a [very similar problem where a FOR /F needed to parse a CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56273436/1012053) with commas in the values. [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56302133/1012053) included a pure batch solution. In that answer I also explained the many issues that make parsing CSV with pure batch difficult.

I've refactored that technique into reusable `:processLine` and `:decodeToken` routines below. The routines require delayed expansion to be enabled before the main processing loop. The technique is designed to put each FOR /F token value into a similarly named environment variable. Enclosing quotes are removed, and doubled `""` within values (if they exist) are reduced to `"`.

The outer loop at the top calls the routines, redoubles all `"`, reorders the fields, and encloses each field within quotes. The outer loop can be easily reformulated to do any manipulation you want. The `:processLine` and `:parseToken` routines at the bottom never have to change.

The code below is ~5 times faster than the [aschipfl answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56466901/1012053). The output is identical, except my code encloses each field within quotes, even those where it is not required. That is perfectly acceptable for CSV.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%A in ("test.csv") do (
  call :processLine A ln
  for /f "tokens=3-6 delims=," %%A in ("!ln!") do (
    for %%v in (A B C D) do call :decodeToken %%v
    echo "!A:"=""!","!B:"=""!","!D:"=""!","!C:"=""!"
  )
)
exit /b


::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: The following routines will work for any CSV as long as no field contains \n
:: and no line approaches the 8191 character limit.

:processLine  forVarCharIn  envVarOut
::
:: Prepares CSV line stored in FOR variable %%forVarIn to be safely parsed by
:: FOR /F with delayed expansion enabled. The result is stored in environment
:: variable envVarOut.
:: 
:: All "" become "
:: All @ become @a
:: All quoted , become @c
:: All ^ become ^^
:: All ! become ^!
:: All fields are enclosed within quotes
:: 
setlocal
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for %%. in (.) do set "ln=%%%1"
set "ln=,%ln:"=""%,"
set "ln=%ln:^=^^^^%"
set "ln=%ln:&=^&%"
set "ln=%ln:|=^|%"
set "ln=%ln:<=^<%"
set "ln=%ln:>=^>%"
set "ln=%ln:!=^^!%"
set "ln=%ln:,=^,^,%"
set ^"ln=%ln:""="%^"
set "ln=%ln:"=""%"
set "ln=%ln:@=@a%"
set "ln=%ln:^,^,=@c%"
endlocal & set "ln=%ln:""="%" !
set "ln=!ln:,,"=,,!"
set "ln=!ln:",,=,,!"
set "ln=!ln:~2,-2!"
set "ln=!ln:^=^^^^!"
endlocal&set "%2=%ln:!=^^^!%"
set "%2=!%2:""="!"
set "%2="!%2:,,=","!"" !
exit /b

:decodeToken  V
::
:: Decodes field in %%V and stores in environment variable V
:: All @c become ,
:: All @a become @
::
for %%. in (.) do set "%1=%%~%1" !
if defined %1 (
  set "%1=!%1:@c=,!"
  set "%1=!%1:@a=@!"
)
exit /b
```

If you are sure that none of your values contain `"` literals, then the loop at the top can be reduced to:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%A in ("test.csv") do (
  call :processLine A ln
  for /f "tokens=3-6 delims=," %%A in ("!ln!") do (
    for %%v in (A B C D) do call :decodeToken %%v
    echo "!A!","!B!","!D!","!C!"
  )
)
exit /b
```

Better yet, since none of the columns you want to preserve contain `@` or `,` or `"`, then the top loop can be greatly simplified without any need for `:parseToken`, gaining another factor of 2 in performance (total of 10 times faster than the aschipfl answer):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%A in (%1) do (
  call :processLine A ln
  for /f "tokens=3-6 delims=," %%A in ("!ln!") do echo %%~A,%%~B,%%~D,%%~C
)
exit /b
```

These routines will work with any CSV as long as none of the CSV values contain a newline, and none of the processed lines exceed the 8191 character limit imposed by batch.

Also, all simple FOR /F techniques are limited to parsing a maximum of 32 tokens. Over at DosTips I demonstrate [how to parse and process hundreds of CSV fields](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=9157). It takes some sophisticated batch coding, but again the routines are reusable, so the outer loop is easy to manage.

Comment: Yes this code works great, thank you @dbenham . Is there a way to make it skip the first line of entries? I tried adding skip=1 and it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: @epickmatt - Sure. Change the top most loop to `for /f skip^=1^ usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%A in ...`

Comment: @epickmatt - If you know that no line begins with `;`, then the loop options become more traditional - `for /f "skip=1 usebackq delims=" %%A in ...`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) approach that allows to extract and reorder specified columns of a CSV file. The column indexes and their order need to be defined in the constant `_LIST` at the top of the script:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILE=%~1"     & rem // (input CSV file; `%~1` is first argument)
set "_LIST=3 4 6 5" & rem // (list of one-based column indexes to return)

rem // Define temporary replacements into pseudo-array `$REPL[]`:
call :SUBSTARR $REPL

rem // Read input CSV file line by line:
for /F "delims=" %%L in ('findstr /N "^" "%_FILE%"') do (
    set "LINE=%%L"
    set /A "INUM=0, LNUM=LINE"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "LINE=!LINE:*:=!"
    rem // Temporarily substitute standard token delimiters but `,`:
    if defined LINE set "LINE=!LINE:\=\b!"
    call :REPLCHAR LINE LINE "^!" "\m"
    for /F "tokens=2* delims=[=]" %%M in ('set $REPL') do (
        if "%%N" == "" (
            call :REPLCHAR LINE LINE "=" "%%M"
        ) else if "%%N" == "*" (
            call :REPLCHAR LINE LINE "*" "%%M"
        ) else (
            if defined LINE set "LINE=!LINE:%%N=%%M!"
        )
    )
    rem // Split line (row) into comma-separated items (fields, cells):
    for %%I in ('!LINE:^,^='^,'!') do (
        endlocal
        set /A "INUM+=1"
        set "ITEM=%%I"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        set "ITEM=!ITEM:','=,!"
        for /F "delims=" %%J in ("$ITEM[!INUM!]=!ITEM:~1,-1!") do (
            endlocal & set "%%J"
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        )
    )
    rem // Rebuild line (row) as per specified list of column indexes:
    set "LINE=," & for %%I in (%_LIST%) do (
        if %%I gtr 0 if %%I leq !INUM! (
            set "LINE=!LINE!!$ITEM[%%I]!,"
        ) else set "LINE=!LINE!,"
    )
    rem // Revert substitution of standard token delimiters but `,`:
    for /F "tokens=2* delims=[=]" %%M in ('set $REPL') do (
        if "%%N" == "" (
            set "LINE=!LINE:%%M==!"
        ) else (
            set "LINE=!LINE:%%M=%%N!"
        )
    )
    call :REPLCHAR LINE LINE "\m" "^!"
    set "LINE=!LINE:\b=\!"
    rem // Return modified line (row):
    >&2 < nul set /P ="!LNUM!:"
    echo(!LINE:~1^,-1!
    endlocal
)

endlocal
exit /B


:NONPRINT
    rem // Obtain several non-printable characters:
    for /F "tokens=1-8 delims=#" %%S in ('
        forfiles /P "%~dp0." /M "%~nx0" /C ^
            "cmd /C echo/0x08#0x09#0x0B#0x0C#0x1A#0x1B#0x7F#0xFF"
    ') do (
        rem // Get back-space, horizontal & vertical tabulators and form-feed:
        set "_BS=%%S" & set "_HT=%%T" & set "_VT=%%U" & set "_FF=%%V"
        rem // Get substitute (end-of-file), escape, delete and fixed space:
        set "_SS=%%W" & set "_ES=%%X" & set "_DE=%%Y" & set "_XX=%%Z"
    )
    exit /B


:SUBSTARR  <rtn_array>
    rem // Obtain non-printable token delimiters:
    call :NONPRINT
    rem // Define substitutions by a pseudo-array:
    for %%R in (
        "[\i]=;"
        "[\e]=="
        "[\s]= "
        "[\t]=%_HT%"
        "[\v]=%_VT%"
        "[\f]=%_FF%"
        "[\x]=%_XX%"
    ) do set "%~1%%~R"
    rem // Define wildcards as substitutions too:
    set "%~1[\a]=*"
    set "%~1[\q]=?"
    set "%~1[\l]=<"
    set "%~1[\g]=>"
    rem set "%~1[\m]=!"
    rem set "%~1[\b]=\"
    rem set "%~1[\c]=,"
    exit /B


:LENGTH  <rtn_length>  <ref_string>
    rem // Determine length of a string:
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "STR=!%~2!"
    if not defined STR (set /A "LEN=0") else (set /A "LEN=1")
    for %%L in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
        if defined STR (
            set "INT=!STR:~%%L!"
            if not "!INT!" == "" set /A "LEN+=%%L" & set "STR=!INT!"
        )
    )
    endlocal & set "%~1=%LEN%"
    exit /B


:REPLCHAR  <rtn_string>  <ref_string>  <val_char>  <val_replace>
    rem // Replace given character in a string by another string:
    setlocal
    set "DXF=!"
    setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
    set "CHR=%~3"
    set "RPL=%~4"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "STR=!%~2!"
    if defined CHR (
        call :LENGTH LEN STR
        call :LENGTH LCH CHR
        set /A "LEN-=1" & for /L %%P in (!LEN!,-1,0) do (
            for %%O in (!LCH!) do (
                if "!STR:~%%P,%%O!" == "!CHR!" (
                    set /A "INC=%%P+%%O" & for %%Q in (!INC!) do (
                        set "STR=!STR:~,%%P!!RPL!!STR:~%%Q!"
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
    if not defined DXF if defined STR set "STR=!STR:"=""!"
    if not defined DXF if defined STR set "STR=!STR:^=^^^^!"
    if not defined DXF if defined STR set "STR=%STR:!=^^^!%" !
    if not defined DXF if defined STR set "STR=!STR:""="!"
    for /F "delims=" %%E in (^""!STR!"^") do (
        endlocal & endlocal & endlocal & set "%~1=%%~E" !
    )
    exit /B
```

The complicated thing is to handle both unquoted and quoted separators (`,`) properly; that explains the size of this script.

Given that the script is called `reconstruct-csv.bat` and the input CSV file is named `File.csv`, run it with the following command line:

```cmd
reconstruct-csv.bat "File.csv"
```

To write the output to another CSV file, say `File_NEW.csv`, rather than to display it, use this:

```cmd
reconstruct-csv.bat "File.csv" > "File_NEW.csv"
```

Comment: Thank you @aschipfl , this solution works must better then anything I have tried. It seems to work the majority of the time. An exception would be this csv file https://www.digikey.ca/products/en?keywords=CD74HC154M96 and click download table.

Comment: Oops, the problem was the question mark `?` in the data; fixed now (same for `<` and `>`; any `*` and `~` might still be problematic, but I'll check)...

Comment: Works great, @aschipfl . It hasn't failed a case yet.

Comment: Problems with `*` as well as `!` and `^` fixed, even empty cells are now treated as expected! The `~` was never a problem...